# How to find largest word that starts with a capital and add a separator and space

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have code that finds largest word that starts with a capital letter. But I need that word to add a separator and space. Any ideas how I should do it properly?

```
char[] skyrikliai = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };
string eilute = "Arvydas (g. 1964 m. gruodzio 19 d. Kaune)– Lietuvos, krepsininkas, olimpinis ir pasaulio cempionas, nuo 2011 m. spalio 24 d.";

static string Ilgiausias(string eilute, char[] skyrikliai)
{
        string[] parts = eilute.Split(skyrikliai,
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string ilgiaus = "";

        foreach (string zodis in parts)
            if ((zodis.Length > ilgiaus.Length) && (zodis[0].ToString() == zodis[0].ToString().ToUpper()))
                ilgiaus = zodis;
        return ilgiaus;
    }
```

It should find word Lietuvos and add , and space

Result should be "Lietuvos, "

Comment: [How to get the longest string in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6524471/1189566)

Comment: Why not just iterate wit a normal for loop and save the index?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, change your `return` statement to `return ilgiaus + ", ";`

Answer (score 3):

I would use LINQ for that:

```
var ilgiaus = parts.Where(s => s[0].IsUpper())
                   .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

if(ilgiaus != null) {
   return ilgiaus + ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use regex and linq. You dont need to split by many characters.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[A-Z]\w*");
string str = "Arvydas (g. 1964 m. gruodzio 19 d. Kaune)– Lietuvos, krepsininkas, olimpinis ir pasaulio cempionas, nuo 2011 m. spalio 24 d.";

string longest = regex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).MaxBy(val => val.Length);
```

if you dont want to use MoreLinq, instead of `MaxBy(val => val.Length)` you can do `OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First()`

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more ingenious and elegant ways, but the following pseudocode should work:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new List<String>();
// add some strings to the generic list
listOfStrings.Add("bla");
listOfStrings.Add("foo");
listOfStrings.Add("bar");
listOfStrings.Add("Rompecabeza");
listOfStrings.Add("Rumpelstiltskin");
. . .
String longestWorld = String.Empty;
. . .
longestWord = GetLongestCapitalizedWord(listOfStrings);
. . .

private String GetLongestCapitalizedWord(List<String> listOfStrings)
{
    foreach (string s in listofstrings)
    {
      if ((IsCapitalized(s) && (s.Len > longestWord.Len)))
      {
          longestWord = s;
      } 
    }
}

private bool IsCapitalized(String s)
{
    return // true or false
}
```